# Method in SQL Server for making a copy of a table and refreshing it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out if there's a method for copying the contents of a main schema into a table of another schema, and then, somehow updating that copy or "refreshing" the copy as the main schema gets updated.

For example:

schema "BBLEARN", has table users

```
SELECT * INTO SIS_temp_data.dbo.bb_users FROM BBLEARN.dbo.users
```

This selects and inserts 23k rows into the table `bb_course_users` in my placeholder schema `SIS_temp_data`.

Thing is, the users table in the BBLEARN schema gets updated on a constant basis, whether or not new users get added, or there are updates to accounts or disables or enables, etc. The main reason for copying the table into a temp table is for data integration purposes and is unrelated to the question at hand.

So, is there a method in SQL Server that will allow me to "update" my new table in the spare schema based on when the data in the main schema gets updated? Or do I just need to run a scheduled task that does a `SELECT * INTO` every few hours?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, go for scheduled task (OR) even better, use Transactional Replication .

Comment: I also vote Transactional Replication

Comment: `Replication` , `Mirroring` , `Log-shipping` are your options if you are on sql server 2012 or later version you also have option of `Always On Availability Groups`.

Comment: Thanks all, went with replication. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a trigger which updates the spare table whenever an updated or insert is performed on the main schema

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190227.aspx